# Connect QuickSight to the private Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to connect QuickSight to the Redshift cluster which is not publicly accessible?

Documentation tells only this:

```
Q: How do I connect my VPC to Amazon QuickSight?

If your VPC has been set up with public connectivity, 
you can add Amazon QuickSight’s IP address range to your database 
instances’ security group rules to enable traffic flow into your VPC 
and database instances.
```

Our VPC is publicly accessible, but Redshift attached to private subnets and has "Publicly accessible" - NO.
(I think the same question is related to the RDS clusters with private access)

Comment: For an answer on how to do this please see this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=772975

Answer (score 1):

You can connect QuickSight to Redshift running in a private VPC now using the 'Enterprise Edition' of QuickSight.

From the FAQ:

> Q: What does private VPC access in the context of Amazon QuickSight
>   mean?
>
> If you have data in AWS (perhaps in Amazon Redshift, Amazon Relational
>   Database Service (RDS), or on EC2) or on-premises in Teradata or SQL
>   Server on servers without public connectivity, this feature is for
>   you. Private VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) Access for QuickSight uses an
>   Elastic Network Interface (ENI) for secure, private communication with
>   data sources in a VPC. It also allows you to use AWS Direct Connect to
>   create a secure, private link with your on-premises resources.

https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/resource-library/faqs/#Security_and_access

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to know if it is possible to connect Quicksight to a Redshift cluster running in private VPC. Unfortunately, since quicksight resources are running outside the customer VPC, it is not possible to access the redshift cluster which is in private VPC. As per our discussion following document talks more about how to configure the security groups for quicksight to access redshift :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/enabling-access-redshift.html

Comment: As of May 2018, access to private VPC data sources is supported by Quicksight. AWS basically creates an ENI within your VPC with your private Data Sources and you can access them via quicksight. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/Amazon-QuickSight-announces-Pay-per-Session-pricing-Private-VPC-Connectivity-and-more/